# How to control WINDOW download dialga-box open/save/cancel with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, dialog

Seems download dialog-box is not a DOM , thus

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

dr = webdriver.Ie(executable_path="IE.exe")

# EXAMPLE  -- download ZIP Jun 20,2018
dr.get('https://usda.library.cornell.edu/concern/publications/j098zb09z?locale=en')
download_CSV =driver.dr.dr.find_element_by_css_selector('#j6731631h > div').click()

# Find the download dialog-box and click save but no function in python selenium.
```

How to apply these function in python through what kind of library ?

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

SendKeys.SendWait(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Dock.jpg");
SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
```

Explanation from CheryJose clearly tell dialog-box is not one of the DOM

[Selenium Web Driver Cancelling Firefox Downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593908/selenium-web-driver-cancelling-firefox-downloads)

How to combine with those script in Python ?
to control the download dialog-box -- these dir & click OK

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-enter-return-key-in-selenium), you could use the send_keys method and Keys.ENTER:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.find_element_by_id("element_id").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Here are some related articles, you could refer to them:

[Python selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.ENTER() Examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/97711/selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.ENTER)

[ENTER key press using Selenium WebDriver with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312033/enter-key-press-using-selenium-webdriver-with-python/38479582)

Comment: Sorry , Zhi , thanks for your answer but , what is the method to control the pop-up dialog-box in IE to choose where to save and click save ?

Comment: [link]https://doccenter.freedomscientific.com/doccenter/doccenter/rs25c51746a0cc/2012-04-25_internetexplorer9/02_internetexplorer9.htm    -- go to part : JAWS 13.0.852 64-bit   , the image show the dialog-box i have to take control

Comment: As far as I know, WebDriver has no capability to access the IE Download dialog boxes presented by browsers when you click on a download link or button. But, we can bypass these dialog boxes using a separate program called "[wget](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/)". More details, you could check [this article](https://www.guru99.com/upload-download-file-selenium-webdriver.html).